# Installing wordpress with using only FTP access

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi I was wondering if it were possible to install wordpress without access to cpanel.

I have access solely to FTP. I've done some research and couldn't find much, I'm not sure if I would be right to assume their is some combination of php scripts that could create a database and then import a .sql file.

Any help would be greatly much appreciated.

Comment: the issue probably will not come with installation of wordpress .. The issue will come with installation of Linux , apache, MySQL and PHP ..

Comment: Try creating database from php first. Then give those details in wp config.php and try installation.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the server owner to create a database for you, once that's done, you just upload the content of the zip downloaded from https://wordpress.org/ and all you need to provide is the credentials for the database (server, DB name, user, password). It's a very simple wizard that will guide you through the entire process.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you go to [wordpress.org](http://wordpress.org/), you can download the latest version of Wordpress. You can unzip this, and upload those files to get started.

However, WordPress requires a MySQL database. So you will need access to a database before you can install Wordpress. This isn't something you can do over FTP.

If you already have the database information, then yes it's possible. Let me know if you need any other help here.